# See if key exists in c++ map

Tags: c++

I have a c++ map where the value type is a `bool`. I need to see if a key exists in the map, and if it doesn't, return `false`. This is my code right now:

```
try {
  return board.at[{x, y}];
}
catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
  return false;
}
```

I don't want to use the `[]` operator because that will initialize the value if it doesn't exist. Is there any way to see if the value exists in the map without a try block?

Comment: `board.find({x,y}) != board.end()`

Comment: Or `board.count({x,y}) > 0` (or if you have C++20 `board.contains({x,y})`)

Comment: You can use `find`, if you need the iterator it returns, else use `count`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::map::find` which will return an iterator the element if found, or `.end` if not found.

```
return board.find({x, y}) != board.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

`return my_map.count({x, y})` is the idiomatic way, and has the advantage of the implicit `bool` conversion.

C++20 adds `bool contains( const Key& key ) const`.